# How do I make a nested for loop faster

Tags: c#

I don't understand how to make this code any faster to get to "no"

```
            int N;
            int t;

            var data = Console.ReadLine();
            var input1 = data.Split(' ');
            N = int.Parse(input1[0]);
            t = int.Parse(input1[1]);

            string[] data2 = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

            int[] A = new int[data2.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < data2.Length; i++)
            {
                A[i] = int.Parse(data2[i]);
            }

            switch (t)
            {
                case 1:
                    for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = i+1; j < A.Length; j++)
                        {
                            if (A[i] != A[j])
                            {
                                if ((A[i] + A[j]) == 7777)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Yes");
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("No");
                    break;
```

It works but it takes too long to get to "No" if there isn't a way to get 7777 from the array.

Comment: Can you explain about your code ?show example Data and expected data?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you seek help, please put more effort in describing your issue. In particular, there are two issues. First, you haven't explained what the code is supposed to do. Second, what does it mean "too long" here? (I know both questions have simple answers but people shouldn't be forced to read between lines).

Comment: Yup, it's not obvious at all what you are trying to do. Your variable naming (things like `data2` and `A`) doesn't help. It would also be good if you provided what your input looks like (so that we might understand what the significance of `7777` is)

Comment: This looks like a coding challenge. The whole idea of a coding challenge is that _**you**_ think about how to do it in a smart way. Just giving you the answer will defy the purpose of the challenge.

Comment: No two equal `int`s add up to an odd `int`.

Answer (score 2):

A few things N is not referenced in your code. And assuming t=1 then you have a few ways to improve your algorithm, for instance with binary search or using a Hash Map.
**Notice I hardcoded some values instead of user input.**

Your snippet time complexity is O(N^2) in the two nested for statement.

**1. Approach binary search,**

Time Complexity: O(NlogN)
Auxiliary Space: O(1)

You can improve your code using binary search doing the following:

- Sort the array
- Iterate from 0 to N-1
- Initialize searchKey = sum – A[i]

  ```
  If(binarySearch(searchKey, A, i + 1, N) == True

   Return True
  ```
- Return False

  ```
  static void Main(string[] args)
       {

           int[] A = { 7777, 7770, 7 };
           int sum = 7777;
           int size = A.Length;

           if (checkTwoSum(A, size, sum))
               Console.Write("Yes");
           else
               Console.Write("No");

           Console.ReadLine();
       }


       private static bool checkTwoSum(int[] A, int size, int sum)
       {
           Array.Sort(A);

           for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
           {
               int key = sum - A[i];
               // calling binarySearch function
               if (binarySearch(A, i + 1, size - 1, key) == true)
               {
                   return true;
               }
           }
           return false;
       }

       static bool binarySearch(int[] A, int low, int high, int key)
       {

           while (low <= high)
           {
               int m = low + (high - low) / 2;

               // Check if searchKey is present at mid
               if (A[m] == key)
                   return true;

               // If searchKey greater, ignore left half
               if (A[m] < key)
                   low = m + 1;

               // If searchKey is smaller, ignore right half
               else
                   high = m - 1;
           }

           // element is not present
           return false;
       }
  ```

**2. Approach hash set**

Time Complexity: O(N)
Auxiliary Space: O(N)

- Initialize an empty hash table s.
- Do the following for each element A[i] in A[]

  If s[x – A[i]] is set then print the pair
  (A[i], x– A[i])

  Insert A[i] into s.

  ```
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           int[] A = { 7777, 7770, 7 };

           int sum = 7777;



           if (checkTwoSum(A,  sum))
               Console.Write("Yes");
           else
               Console.Write("No");

           Console.ReadLine();
       }


       private static bool checkTwoSum(int[] A,  int sum)
       {
           HashSet<int> s = new HashSet<int>();
           for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; ++i)
           {
               int temp = sum - A[i];

               // checking for condition
               if (s.Contains(temp))
               {                 
                   return true;
               }
               s.Add(A[i]);
           }
           return false;
       }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to find out whether a given `int` array `A` has two elements `A[i]` and `A[j]` whose sum is `7777`. (For `int`s, `A[i] != A[j]` is no additional constraint, as `7777` is odd.)

If `A` is very long, it may be faster to sort it first into the sorted array `S` and then check efficiently for every element `S[i]` whether `S` contains `7777 - S[i]` instead of testing every pair of elements.

You can even use two indices `i` and `j` starting at `i = 0` (at the smallest element) and `j = S.Length - 1` (at the largest element) and either increment `i` as long as `S[i] + S[j] < 7777` or decrement `j` as long as `S[i] + S[j] > 7777` until you find `S[i] + S[j] == 7777` (in which case the answer is *"Yes"*) or reach `i == j` (in which case the answer is *"No"*).